# How to make f{char} case insensitive?

Tags: vimrc, cursor-movement, cursor-motions, letter-case, find

Regarding this command:

```
f{char}                 To [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the right.  The
                        cursor is placed on {char} |inclusive|.
                        {char} can be entered as a digraph |digraph-arg|.
                        When 'encoding' is set to Unicode, composing
                        characters may be used, see |utf-8-char-arg|.
                        |:lmap| mappings apply to {char}.  The CTRL-^ command
                        in Insert mode can be used to switch this on/off
                        |i_CTRL-^|.
```

I would like to change its behaviour as such. Take this sample string, in which `^` indicates the cursor position:

```
fooBar(); // boat programming SO meme
^
```

The keystroke: `fb` would ordinarily jump to:

```
fooBar(); // boat programming SO meme
             ^
```

I would rather have it jump to:

```
fooBar(); // boat programming SO meme
   ^
```

Make sense? Ideally the solution should continue to work with ';'

Comment: Have you tried to do it by yourself? Because you could easily adapt [Christian's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15361/1841) to your previous question.

Comment: Ref: [Case insensitive f key in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280247/case-insensitive-f-key-in-vim)

Answer (score 2):

A basic version of this is actually in the reference manual as an example of how to use the `getchar()` function:

> This example redefines "f" to ignore case:
>
> ```
> :nmap f :call FindChar()<CR>
> :function FindChar()
> :  let c = nr2char(getchar())
> :  while col('.') < col('$') - 1
> :    normal l
> :    if getline('.')[col('.') - 1] ==? c
> :      break
> :    endif
> :  endwhile
> :endfunction
> ```

See `:help getchar()`.

Note that this doesn't handle counts or other, related commands (`t`, `F`, `T`, `;`, `,`), although it could be adapted to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner solution built on top of `getchar())`

```
nnoremap <silent> f :silent! exe "normal! ". substitute(matchstr(getline('.')[col('.') :], '\v\c.{-}'.nr2char(getchar())), '.', "l", "g")<cr>
```

The idea is to extract all the characters from the current position till the character typed, and to convert them in as many `<right>` as necessary. Note that as this is a one liner mapping definition, I cannot use `\<right>` easily, hence the more obfuscated `l`.

Note: I don't use a loop as loops are slow and a PITA to debug.

In order to support a *count*, it could become:

```
nnoremap <silent> f :<c-u>silent! exe "normal! ". substitute(matchstr(getline('.')[col('.') :], '\v\c(.{-}'.nr2char(getchar()).'){'.v:count1.'}'), '.', "l", "g")<cr>
```

What changes here is the use of `:<c-u>` to clear the count, and the fact that I've surrounded the pattern `.{-}Z` (by `Z` I meant the result of `nr2char(getchar())`) with `(...){v:count1}` (lose syntax) to count exactly the number of *whatever Z* I want.